# I want to add values under same key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"locs" : {
        "-Lci8jGrXCEP-r6LBxD8" : {
          "title" : "Marriage"
        },
        "-Lci9UNW80J2Jap_UHwj" : {
          "title" : "Visit"
        }
      },
```

My firebase realtime database looks like this. I want to add three other values under this same push key namely latitude and longitude and address.

```
  mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").push().child("title").setValue(text.getText().toString());
```

This works in first activity. In second activity I retrieve lat and long and save it in a string lat and long respectively. Now I want these two values and addr to be saved under this same key.

This is my expected result

```
"locs" : {
        "-Lci8jGrXCEP-r6LBxD8" : {
          "title" : "Marriage"
          "lat"   : "xxx.xxxxxx"
          "long"  : "xxx.xxxxxx"
          "addr"  : "Street 112 xxxx"
        },
        "-Lci9UNW80J2Jap_UHwj" : {
          "title" : "Visit"
          "lat"   : "xxx.xxxxxx"
          "long"  : "xxx.xxxxxx"
          "addr"  : "Street 1212 Flat 6"
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do two things:

- Make sure the second activity knows the key to update. You can do this either by passing the key along from the first activity to the next (in an intent or in shared preferences), or by looking it up in the second activity based on some other unique property that you know the value of.
- Update the location for that key, instead of generating a new one. You do this by calling `update()` instead of `set()` and using `child(key)` instead of `push()`. So:

  ```
  Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  values.put("title", "new updated title");
  values.put("newprop", "value of new prop");
  mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").child(key).updateChildren(values);
  ```

Comment: Thanks I retrieved key using this 
```
 `String key= mDatabase.push().getKey();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Location.this,GeoFenceActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("key",key);`

```
But the retrieved key is different from original key.

in 2nd activity

`final String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");

mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").child(value).updateChildren(values);`

Comment: Every time you call `push()` is generate a location with a new unique key. So be sure to use the new key in both the original activity and the second activity.

Comment: I used `push().getkey()` and used intent to transfer the value to second activity. But it is a different key over there. Not the one i pushed. Any solution?

Comment: The solution is to only call `push()` once. For example use the key you generate with the code in your comment to write the child node with both locations. So with `mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").child(key).child("title").setValue(text.getText().toString());` in activity one and `updateChildren()` in acticity 2.